# Firebase Firestore Query v9 Works "desc" but not "asc" (indexed both)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to order by price in both directions. However, it currently only works "desc" and not "asc".

The 'direction' variable is either set to "asc" or "desc" depending on button click. I have checked - it is definitely asc or desc.

**The request returns 50 items on "desc" but returns an empty array on "asc". Surely this doesn't make sense as it is the same request reading the same data just in another direction.**

```
    const reference = await query(
      collection(firestore, "assets"),
      where("status.locked", "==", true),
      orderBy("status.price", direction),
      limit(count),
      startAfter(lastVisible?.status?.price ?? "")
    );
```

This is how direction is initialised:
(filtering either is "High to Low" or "Low to High")

```
let direction = filtering === "High to Low" ? "desc" : "asc";
```

Comment: Edited that in! Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: "The request even only fails "asc" when I hardcode it." If it fails with a hard-coded value, it's best to show *that*. What does "fails" mean though? Is there an error message?

Comment: Edited and improve the question. It was unclear.

"The request returns 50 items on "desc" but returns an empty array on "asc". Surely this doesn't make sense as it is the same request reading the same data just in another direction."

Comment: I wonder if you're populating `lastVisible` correctly. Does it work if you remove the `startAfter(lastVisible?.status?.price ?? "")`?

Comment: Ok. The startAfter was definitely the issue as removing it now means the items are returned in the correct order. But I don't have pagination anymore! Will try to fix that. THANK YOU

Comment: So it turns out the solution was to put 'null' not an "" (empty string) as the search term for the first page. However, you did identify that the issue was with that function! Thats amazing - thank you puf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discovered in the comments, the value of `lastVisible` is not correct for an ascending sort in your case.

Since you're using `startAfter(lastVisible?.status?.price ?? "")`, you will need to find the inverted `lastVisible` object when you invert the sort order. Alternatively, you can invert the logic and use `endBefore` instead.